# GWT-app permutation script not cached on iOS devices when web-app capable

Tags: gwt, web-applications, ios6, linker, cache-manifest

Recently I discovered a problem relating to caching in my GWT app when running on iOS 6.x devices *in web-app (fullscreen) mode*. The problem is that **iOS seems to ignore my cache policy directives on the bulky permutation files** (`<hash>.cache.html`.)

I have a servlet filter setting cache headers on static resources including `*.cache.html` files, e.g.:

```
# Response header snippet
Expires: Fri, 26 Jul 2013 09:58:28 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=8640000
ETag: W/"322107-1359629388000"
Last-Modified: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 10:49:48 GMT
```

However, as soon as I put in web-app support and add the app to my home screen the iOS device will request the permutation file on *every load* and sends neither `If-None-Match` nor `If-Modified-Since` request headers. Web-app support is added via a `<meta>` tag:

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

I haven't been able to find this issue documented anywhere and am not certain it is a bug. It *is*, however, what I have experienced. Caching works as expected in my desktop browser where I can inspect the received headers. Nowhere do I sniff the user agent and distinguish based on this information so all clients will receive the same headers.

---

I was able to "solve" the immediate problem via an HTML5 cache manifest file as presented in this [Google I/O talk: "Google I/O 2010 - GWT Linkers target HTML5 WebWorkers & more"](http://youtu.be/omBURP0MxcI?t=33m46s) where a custom [GWT Linker](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/core/ext/Linker.html) generates a manifest file containing *all generated permutations*, e.g.:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
<hash1>.cache.html
<hash2>.cache.html
...
<hashN>.cache.html
```

And adds the manifest directly in the host page (`<module>.html`):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="[module-path]/offline.manifest">
...
```

This is all well *except* that *all* clients will now [have to load *all* permutations](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag#section13) eventhough *only one* is needed! I my case 18 permutations each ~5MB over 3G or Edge :( Is this really the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was investigating a little further and finding that **instead of adding the manifest reference in the host page I could add it to *all* permutation scripts.** The manifest itself can be a generic (and practically empty) file:

> Authors are encouraged to include the main page in the manifest also, but in practice the page that referenced the manifest is automatically cached even if it isn't explicitly mentioned. ([source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#introduction-5))

Thus, I wrote a simple `Linker` that:

1. Creates an offline manifest file
2. Adds a `manifest` attribute to the `<html>` tag of all permutation scripts (`*.cache.html`).

The `Linker` is called `ManifestLinker` and is rather simple:

```java
package com.example.linker;

// Imports

@LinkerOrder(Order.POST)
public class ManifestLinker extends AbstractLinker {
    private static final String MANIFEST_FILE = "manifest.nocache.appcache";
    private static final String HTML_FIND = "<html>";
    private static final String HTML_REPLACE = "<html manifest=\"" + MANIFEST_FILE + "\">";

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.google.gwt.core.ext.Linker#getDescription()
     */
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "`Manifest Linker`: Adds AppCache support for static `.cache.html` resources.";
    }

    @Override
    public ArtifactSet link(TreeLogger logger, LinkerContext context, ArtifactSet artifacts) throws UnableToCompleteException {
        ArtifactSet output = new ArtifactSet(artifacts);

        output.add(buildManifest(logger));

        for (EmittedArtifact artifact : artifacts.find(EmittedArtifact.class)) {
            if (artifact.getVisibility() == Visibility.Public && artifact.getPartialPath().endsWith(".cache.html")) {
                logger.log(TreeLogger.TRACE, "Processing file: " + artifact.getPartialPath());

                String cacheHtml = Util.readStreamAsString(artifact.getContents(logger));
                if (cacheHtml.startsWith(HTML_FIND)) {
                    cacheHtml = HTML_REPLACE + cacheHtml.substring(HTML_FIND.length()); // Replace `<html>` tag.

                    output.replace(copyArtifact(logger, artifact, cacheHtml));
                }
            }
        }

        logger.log(TreeLogger.INFO, "Manifest created and linked successfully.");

        return output;
    }

    private EmittedArtifact copyArtifact(TreeLogger logger, EmittedArtifact original, String contents) throws UnableToCompleteException {
        EmittedArtifact copy = emitString(logger, contents, original.getPartialPath());
        copy.setVisibility(original.getVisibility());

        return copy;
    }

    private EmittedArtifact buildManifest(TreeLogger logger) throws UnableToCompleteException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CACHE MANIFEST\n")
               .append("# Generated by ")
               .append(getClass().getSimpleName())
               .append(": ")
               .append(System.currentTimeMillis())
               .append(".\n\n")
               .append("NETWORK:\n")
               .append("*\n");

        SyntheticArtifact manifest = emitString(logger, builder.toString(), MANIFEST_FILE);

        return manifest;
    }
}
```

In my `<module>.gwt.xml` file I define and add the linker:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
    ...
    <define-linker name="manifest" class="com.example.linker.ManifestLinker" />
    <add-linker name="manifest" />
    ...
```

Also, I make sure that the right content type is set via my `web.xml`:

```xml
...
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>appcache</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
...
```

The emitted `manifest.nocache.appcache` is simple too:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Generated by ManifestLinker: 1366702621298.

NETWORK:
*
```